# Data type to store more than 20 digits of value

Tags: c++

```
‪#‎include‬ <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double n,m,a, count=0;
    cin>>n>>m>>a;
    double length=n;
    while(m>0)
    {
        while(n>0)
        {
            count=count+1;
            n=n-a;
        }
        m=m-a;
        n=length;
    }
    cout<<count;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

sample input

```
6 6 4
```

output

```
4 (working fine)
```

sample input

```
1000000000 1000000000 13
```

output

```
___ no output
```

Means it is working fine with small range of "count" value. If value exceeds from its limit then it is not printing anything. I have tried all range of values. Please help me

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Search the web for "`BigInt`"

Comment: Maybe it just takes a while, have you tried waiting?

Comment: You could try using something like long long, an unsigned long long can be as large as 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.  _int64 would do the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting no output with the sample input of `1000000000 1000000000 13` is because it takes far too long.

The inner loop runs 76923077 times, and the outer loop runs 76923077 times. This means that the inner code `count=count+1` is running 5.91 x 10^15 times. Even if the inner code could run in a picosecond (it can't), it would take more than 98 hours to complete.